# How to make alliterative sentences?

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm a beginner in Java and I'm working on a project that requires us to make alliterative sentences. The problem I'm running into is that the while loop will not stop even after finding the noun with first char matches with adjective. This is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class WordList {
int count = 1;
String Adj = randomAdj();
String Noun = randomNoun();


public String randomAdj() {

    ArrayList<String> Adjs = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner adj = null;
    try {
        adj = new Scanner(new File("adj.txt"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't not open file");
    }
    while (adj.hasNext()) {
        Adjs.add(adj.next());
    }
    adj.close();

    Random rand = new Random();
    String randomAdj = Adjs.get(rand.nextInt(Adjs.size()));
    System.out.printf("%s ", randomAdj);
    return randomAdj;
}

public String randomNoun() {

    ArrayList<String> Nouns = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner noun = null;
    try {
        noun = new Scanner(new File("noun.txt"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't not open file");
    }
    while (noun.hasNext()) {
        Nouns.add(noun.next());
    }
    noun.close();
    Random rand = new Random();
    String randomNoun = Nouns.get(rand.nextInt(Nouns.size()));
    //System.out.printf("%s ", randomNoun);
    return randomNoun;
}

public void randomWordStartingWith() {


    while(Adj.charAt(0) != Noun.charAt(0))
    {
        count++;
        //System.out.println(Adj + " " + randomNoun() + " " + count);
        randomNoun();

    }
    System.out.println(Adj + " " + Noun + " " + count);

}
```

}

Comment: Can I suggest that you load your random noun and adjective lists just once, and reuse that list every time you want to pick a random one? Right now you load the whole file every time you want just one item - and you call this in a loop.

Comment: A suggestion which might help you: what if you were to load the noun/adjective lists into a `Map<Character, List<String>>`, where the key is the first letter, and the value is a list of all the words starting with that letter...

Comment: I would but unfortunately I don't know how that function works since I'm still a beginner at java. But i'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your loop is that you never update `Noun` (or `Adj`):

```
while(Adj.charAt(0) != Noun.charAt(0))
{
    count++;
    Noun = randomNoun();
}
```

I've removed the commented line:

```
//System.out.println(Adj + " " + randomNoun() + " " + count);
```

If you want to uncomment this line, you should use the value of `Noun`, not call `randomNoun()` again - and probably put it after the `Noun =` line.